# Create new Dictionary from an existing by filtering some values

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok, so here is my problem.

I having arrays of objects(Person class) added to dictionary. Each contains fullName and few other properties. I created dictionary by loop generating keys by

```
NSString -stringWithFormat:@"person%d"
```

Just for ease lets say my dictionary looks like

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"person1": @"Ilena Jennifer DCruz", @"person2":@"James Bond", @"person3":@"Skylark", @"person4":@"Xan Xiaa Zuang Ming"};
```

Now, I need a dictionary with only first name of for each person.

How can I have that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that if your data is well structured. You can enumerate through collection to get just the names. If this process is repetitive, consider making a Model Class for Person. As a note your structure of dictionary can be improved, if the identifier of a person is going to be "person1","person2", you may just need an array.

Comment: @Anupdas: i am getting from JSON

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"person1": @"Ilena Jennifer DCruz",
                     @"person2":@"James Bond",
                     @"person3":@"Skylark",
                     @"person4":@"Xan Xiaa Zuang Ming"
                     };

NSMutableDictionary *firstNameDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSString *key in dict) {
    [firstNameDict setObject:[dict[key]componentsSeparatedByString:@" "][0]
                      forKey:key];
}
NSLog(@"->%@",firstNameDict);
```

Output:

```
->{
   person1 = Ilena;
   person2 = James;
   person3 = Skylarl;
   person4 = Xan; 
 }
```